# Unity - Adjust model materials

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a model that I have to use in game. I imported the model and extract materials as: 'clothes', 'phong1' and 'skin'

But its applying 'phong1' material to all over the model and nothing changes when i change the color on 'clothes' or 'skin' material.

[Weirdness on the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfzjj.png)

Do you guys have any idea to how to fix that? Im sharing original .fbx and texture to be more identifying.

https://easyupload.io/lsowue

Comment: This should belong to https://answers.unity.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the attached MeshRenderer or SkinnedMeshRenderer and check if the materials are passed in right order.

Comment: Replacing some of the materials in SkinnedMeshRenderer solved my issue. Thank you Hasnain!